# Highcharts text labels for y-axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts and would like to display a simple column graph, but instead of using numeric values for the y-axis, I would like to use text values.
For example, instead of `[0,5,10,15,20]` I would like to use `[Very Low,Low,Medium,High,Very High]`.

I noticed it's somewhat possible to do this with plot bands, but that still shows the numeric y-axis labels and just puts the text beside them. I want to only show the text labels.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can change the labels by using a [label formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels.formatter). Assuming your data is formed appropriately, you can do something like the following:

```
var yourLabels = ["Very Low", "Low", "Medium", "High", "Very High"];
var yourChart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    //...
    yAxis: {        
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                return yourLabels[this.value];
            }
        }
    }
    //...
});
```

Comment: Just trying to achieve the same thing - the graph sets up nicely as per this method (with labels not numerical values) however I can't get my data to plot to it - how do I submit data that maps onto this? (At the moment I've got:
`series: [{
     name: 'Status',
     data: [No Existing Services, Inpatient Only, Inpatient Only]
     }`

Answer (score 15):

Declare an object which will be used to switch the values you want to change, like the following.

```
var change = {
    0: 'Very Low',
    5: 'Low',
    10: 'Medium',
    15: 'High',
    20: 'Very High'
};
```

Then on your chart options use labels formatter to switch it.

```
yAxis: {
    labels: {
        formatter: function() {
            var value = change[this.value];
            return value !== 'undefined' ? value : this.value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: would be nicer to use a switch

Comment: @nicolallias No, it would not. What if the mapping between numeric and textual values is maintained in a database?