# TypeScript Intellisense works differently if I define Object in Different Ways

Tags: intellisense, typescript

I am trying to convert some existing JavaScript code by using TypeScript, One example I am using is to create Highcharts classes, the Highcharts definition is from https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/highcharts/highcharts.d.ts

We all know HighchartsOptions has a property `title`.

If I define the object in this way, I have intellisense

[image]

But if I define object this way

[image]
I don't have the intellisense.

Any specific reason why Visual Studio behaves differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a bug. See [this issue on CodePlex](http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/440) to track when it gets fixed.