# Highchart - Use a formatter on PlotLine labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm using highchart to show some text next to a plot line on the xAxis. I would like to customize each label from a formatter function as it is possible on every other labels in the chart.

I've seen [another topic on this matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14887513/highcharts-typescript-y-axis-label) but they're using TypeScript and I don't.

What I'm doing is :

```
vay chart = new HighChart({
...
xAxis: {
        plotLines: [{
            id: "plotLines",
            zIndex: 15,
            color: myColor,
            width: 1,
            value: theXvalue, //x value where to show the line
            label: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return " VAL > "+this.value;
               }
            },
        }]
    },
    ...
});
```

If I set the 'text' value in the label it shows up and it works like a charm.

Any help to use a formatter for those labels ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot use formatter, you should define content of label in text object, which can be wrapped in html elements, but then you need to set [useHTML(http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.plotLines.label.useHTML) parameter

Comment: Thanks for your answer. More than a format, I needed the callback on those label display...  any clue on how to achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Set the useHTML value to true and set your html content inside text. Here is an example of how to achieve it http://jsfiddle.net/9mvwpqf3/1/

`yAxis: {
        plotLines: [{
            color: 'red',
            width: 2,
            value: 100,
             label: {
          useHTML: true,
        text: '<button>Click Me</button>',
                 },
        }]
    },`