# Highcharts with dynamic yaxis labels as strings

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've been trying to add some custom yAxis labels to highcharts but I've not been able to so far. I've tried using formatter from a predefined array of strings and I've tried addAxis method but that doesn't get me the results I'm looking for.

Basically I have some numbers (lets say 4 and 4000) and I want to have these as my yLabels. However, I do **NOT** want the giant space between them. They need to be one right after the other and in ascending order. I cannot figure out how to do this leaving them as integers and I cannot figure out how to dynamically add them to highcharts as strings. I'm not even sure if this is possible

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the [Y-axis label formatter documentation from Highcharts](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.labels.formatter) you're probably looking for. I wrote this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g3pLz0e2/) to simulate the custom y-axis functionality you were wanting, although I'm not sure how you want to map those values to the x-axis data.  This should give you a good starting point.

Code for reference:

```
$('#container').highcharts({

    yAxis: {
        categories: ['4', '4000', 'Foobar'],

        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.value;
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [0, 1, 2]
    }]
});
```

This [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987457/highcharts-text-labels-for-y-axis) may also help although I noticed some dead links.

Comment: this does help, however how do I dynamically add to categories?

Comment: I'd imagine just setting "categories" to a variable, modify it, and force a redraw.  There may be a better way of doing this though and I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: I'm also adding my series's dynamically, this is proving tough!