# Highcharts - Plot by week with and label formatter

Tags: highcharts, label, gantt-chart

I'm trying to create a project scheduling plot using Highcharts and I'm having a bit of an issue separating the values I want to plot from the axis labels. For example, I want a task to start in week 20 of 2016 so what I have been doing is just concatenating the year and week into: "201620" and then turning it into a category. For my labels I simply split off the last two digits from the first four so it looked like "2016-20". I accomplished this by using the label formatter code in the yAxis portion of the code:

```
formatter: function() {
  var FullDate = this.value.toString();
  var FiscalYear = FullDate.substring(0, 4);
  var WorkWeek = FullDate.substring(4, 6);
  return FiscalYear + '-' + WorkWeek;
}
```

This works great as long as all the tasks happen within the same year ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2b3cma8k/1/)).

My problem is what to do when 2017 comes around (there shouldn't be 99 weeks in the year, [see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eq2b26c5/1/)). I therefore am converting the work weeks into an auto-calculated integer but I still want my plots to display "2016-20".

So my question is: **How can I plot integers but display separate text on an axis?**

[Link to working example](http://jsfiddle.net/eq2b26c5/).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There should be an easier way using the `Highcharts.dateFormat()` function (see http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.dateFormat). What does the source data for your task dates look like? Are they, for example, timestamps?

Comment: Mike: The data is a concatenation of two fields: Year and Week. So I'm not storing it as a date. I think I may have found a solution using a version of the solution from [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987457/highcharts-text-labels-for-y-axis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added an array at that stored my axis label and I think I solved my issue. [Link to fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/emswo30v/).

```
var WorkWeekLabels = {
            '1967' : '2016 - 23',
            '1968' : '2016 - 24',
            '1969' : '2016 - 25',
            '1970' : '2016 - 26',
            '1971' : '2016 - 27',
            '1972' : '2016 - 28',
            '1973' : '2016 - 29',
...etc...
}
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987457/highcharts-text-labels-for-y-axis) pretty much solved it for me.